# Disable animation when switching/swiping between desktops on osx 10.9

Tags: osx-mavericks

I've recently starting to learn how to code and I've been using my MacBook Air 13", w/ osx 10.9.

At first I learned not to use my trackpad, better to instead Command-Tab between my various apps, which greatly increased my productivity.

Next I started three-finger swiping or pressing control & left/right between "desktops" (that way I could full-screen Sublime, Terminal, a pdf, etc.)... another great productivity boost.

Perhaps I am getting faster at typing and thinking about code, but I recently found that when I swipe between desktops there is a slight lag. For example, swiping between sublime and terminal will result in some text in sublime then the remainder in terminal if you do it relatively quickly. It is only maybe a one second delay, but this does slow me down when I have the Hartl Tutorial, Sublime and Terminal all open on different desktops and I am moving between them a lot (as I am doing now).

I assume that disabling the animation which occurs when moving between desktops will allow me to start typing code earlier on the destination desktop... so if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to disable that animation it would be appreciated!

Comment: I noted quite the same thing on my Mac, but after first update (=reboot) it was gone. ...or maybe I just stopped noticing it? ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using OS X; you may find help on [apple.se].

Comment: Ahha, cool ... wasn't even aware of "Ask Different"... something new each day! Love it! If anyone else comes across this question or knows the answer please checkout http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107877/how-to-turn-off-slide-transition-when-switching-between-two-full-screen-applicat as it goes over my same question.